# I want 100 requests on MKReverseGeocoder per minute. Is it correct?

Tags: iphone, mkreversegeocoder

I want 100 requests on MKReverseGeocoder. Is it correct? Does apple block my app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses Google and the docs clearly state

> ```
> Send at most one reverse-geocoding request for any one user action.
> ```